# How to perform multiple updates in single merge statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

I need to update multiple columns in a single merge statement with two differ conditions like 
1. row_ind = N; update some columns
2. row_ind = Y; update some columns

How i will achieves this one in sqlserver / oracle

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET TARGET.NodeId = SOURCE.StartNodeId,
           TARGET.LinkId = SOURCE.Id where row_ind ='Y'

UPDATE SET TARGET.NodeId = SOURCE.EndNodeId,
           TARGET.LinkId = SOURCE.Id where row_ind = 'N';
```

Comment: Which database system are you actually using?  For SqlServer you could look at table variables and update over a join

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't put the logic in the source subquery? That would make the update section clearer. It would definitely work in Oracle, and probably work in SQL Server too.

Answer (score 1):

For [tsql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  you can try using `AND <clause_search_condition>`

```
MERGE   
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ]   
    [ INTO ] <target_table> [ WITH ( <merge_hint> ) ] [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
    USING <table_source>   
    ON <merge_search_condition>  
    [ WHEN MATCHED [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]     <==
        THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]  
<merge_matched>::=  
     { UPDATE SET <set_clause> | DELETE }
```

as you can have multiple WHEN MATCHED with different additional condition after AND you can create multiple updates using single merge statement.

```
WHEN MATCHED AND row_ind ='Y' THEN
UPDATE SET TARGET.NodeId = SOURCE.StartNodeId,
           TARGET.LinkId = SOURCE.Id 
WHEN MATCHED AND row_ind ='N' THEN
UPDATE SET TARGET.NodeId = SOURCE.EndNodeId,
           TARGET.LinkId = SOURCE.Id ;
```

in [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) you cannot do this as only one merge_update_clause is allowed

MERGE is not supported by MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use "CASE..WHEN" to achieve the same in Oracle as follows:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.NODEID = CASE ROW_IND
    WHEN 'Y'   THEN SOURCE.STARTNODEID
    WHEN 'N'   THEN SOURCE.ENDNODEID
END,
TARGET.LINKID = SOURCE.ID;
```

Thanks